# <= displays records of < in mysql query

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I am using the following query to get records having the UpdatedAt field in between 2015-02-02 and 2015-02-06

```
SELECT `TotalPrice`,`UpdatedAt` FROM `price` WHERE `UpdatedAt`>= '2015-02-02' AND `UpdatedAt`<='2015-02-06' ORDER BY `UpdatedAt` DESC
```

And this is displaying UpdatedAt from 2015-02-05 to 2015-02-02. And the table has records for 2015-02-06 also. Kindly indicate the mistake i have done.

Comment: @danronmoon No it does not help me :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `UpdatedAt` has a *time* component.  Here is an alternative `where` clause:

```
WHERE `UpdatedAt` >= '2015-02-02' AND `UpdatedAt` < '2015-02-07'
```

You might find this more readable as:

```
WHERE `UpdatedAt` >= '2015-02-02' AND
      `UpdatedAt` < DATE_ADD('2015-02-06', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

What you should *not* get in the habit of doing is:

```
WHERE DATE(UpdatedAt) >= '2015-02-02' AND DATE(UpdatedAt) <= '2015-02-06'
```

Although technically correct, this prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: Lovely, I do quite like the syntax `updatedAt < '2015-02-06' + INTERVAL 1 DAY` however

Comment: @Arth . . . I also like that syntax.  But because MySQL can be funky with `now()`, I try to avoid it and explicitly use `date_add()` and `date_sub()`.

Comment: Ooh, I wasn't aware of the funkiness of NOW(), do you have a reference?

Comment: @Arth . . . The documentation makes clear that `now()` returns a string or a number ("Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. ").  However, I think it might be working now with `interval`.  At least, it seems to work in SQL Fiddle.